# Zoom meeting sdk in react native

Tags: react-native, zoom-sdk, zoom-meeting

How to integrate zoom meeting sdk in react-native? Can anyone suggest me the right document for the integration. Suggest me any library or codes to integrate the zoom functionalities in react native application.

Comment: Did you checked this documentation? :- https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/react-native/

Comment: Thanks for responding. Is there any free version available for the video SDK?

Comment: If you find my answer helpful please upvote, and i don't think that is there any free version of it available you will get only free trial.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [sdk](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/react-native/) for implementing zoom in react-native.

To join a session, make the following call on the Zoom Video SDK instance:

```
const doZoomThings = async() => {
  await zoom.joinSession({
    sessionName: 'name of video session',
    token: 'JWT goes here',
    username: 'name of user as it will appear in the video session to others',
    audioOptions: {
      connect: true,
      mute: false,
    },
    videoOptions: {
      localVideoOn: true,
    },
    videoOptions: {
      localVideoOn: true,
    },
  });
};
```

Render video using this:

```
<View style={styles.fullScreenVideo}>
  <VideoView
    user={fullScreenUser}
    sharing={fullScreenUser?.userId === sharingUser?.userId}
    onPress={() => {
      isKeyboardOpen ? toggleUI() : Keyboard.dismiss();
    }}
    fullScreen
  />
</View>
```

check Audio connections

```
user.audioStatus.isMuted(); // Check if the user is muted
user.audioStatus.isTalking(); // Check if the user is talking
user.audioStatus.getAudioType(); // Check if the user is connected
```

start sharing your screen :

```
const zoomHelper = await zoom.shareHelper;
const isOtherSharing = await zoomHelper.isOtherSharing();
const isShareLocked = await zoomHelper.isShareLocked();
if (isOtherSharing) {
  Alert.alert('Other is sharing');
} else if (isShareLocked) {
  Alert.alert('Share is locked by host');
}
zoom.shareHelper.shareScreen();
```